# REST API URL resource with parameter inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, url

In a project I am currently working on I was given the following HTTP POST command definition below (client requirement written in stone) which I have to implement into a webserver which is currently based on a MEAN STACK.

```
{{Host}}/Products('{{ProductId}}')/Data.Order
```

How can I implement this? I am not used to parameters inside parentheses for a specific resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express should be able to resolve the path-placeHolder (through `:<placeHolder>)`, even if it's within this rather unusual parentheses. So try defining your endpoint as follows:

```
app.post('/Products(:productId)/Data.Order',(req, res, next) => {
    console.log("productId is", req.params.productId);

    res.status(201).end();
})
```

Calling this endpoint with POST `http://<host>:<port>/Products(12345)/Data.Order` should log `12345` to the console.

Comment: Wow! You made my day!